# How to get integer out of Poco::Any

Tags: c++, c++11, poco-libraries

I use `Poco::Any` with various integer types, e.g.:

```
Poco::Any x = 15;
Poco::Any y = (size_t)15;
Poco::Any z = 15L;
```

Later on I want to work with an integer value:

```
void func(Poco::Any &a)
{
```

How can I extract any integer out of this?  One way would be:

```
long n;
if ( auto *p = Poco::AnyCast<int>(&a) )
    n = *p;
else if ( auto *p = Poco::AnyCast<long>(&a) )
    n = *p;
```

and repeat for every integral type. But this is ugly. Is there a better way?

I have tried:

```
Poco::Dynamic::Var var(a);
auto n = var.convert<int>(var);
```

however this throws an exception which comes from `VarHolder.h`:

```
virtual void convert(Int32& val) const;
    /// Throws BadCastException. Must be overriden in a type
    /// specialization in order to suport the conversion.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Poco::Any` (which is a port of [boost:any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/any.html)) is essentially a "one-way road" in regards to types - you can put literally anything into it but, when you want to get the value out, you have to know exactly what is inside; in that sense, `any` is stricter than the C++ language itself.

`DynamicAny` (a.k.a. [Poco::Dynamic::Var](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/master/Foundation/include/Poco/Dynamic/Var.h#L41)) is built on the `any` foundation, "softening" it on the data retrieval side; it was introduced precisely to alleviate that constraint.

See [DynamicAny, Part I](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1502) for an in-depth explanation:

> Although it provides a mechanism for dynamic type discovery (Listing
> 2.), boost::any does not itself get involved into such activity, nor is it willing to cooperate in implicit conversions between values of
> different types.

So, if you want to stick with Poco::Any, you will have to discover what is in it:

```
void func(Poco::Any &a)
{
  long n;
  if (a.type() == typeid(int))
    n = Poco::AnyCast<int>(a);
  else if (a.type() == typeid(long))
    n = Poco::AnyCast<long>(a);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks. `Dynamic::Var` seems to be more apprioriate for what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AnyCast` or `RefAnyCast` - though you could create your own wrapper class around `Any` with a new method implemented that will return the underlying object type if you don't like using either typedef or the above.